# Read data from file stored in rows and columns

Tags: python, file

> I have a text file with data arranged into rows and columns.I want to
>    read data as [row][column] value from the file
>
> Example:
>    1 2 31 4
>    2 3 41 456
>    4 5 90 1120
>    3 4 55 1001
>   For Example If I need to get the value at first row,third column i.e 31
>   How can I do so??

Comment: Do you know how to open a file and how to read a line?

Comment: No i don't know

Comment: You might want to pick up a tutorial (there's some listed [here](https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F))

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a tutorial or code writing service.  Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You should spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples.  There are many other good online resources.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#module-csv) module using space as the delimiter. Process row-by-row if that suits your application, or read the data into a list of lists to provide random access to the data. Example:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv') as f:
    data = [row for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')]

print(data[0][2])
print(data[3][3])
```

Output:

```
31
1001
```

Comment: will it work for text file?

Comment: CSV is a text file with the data formatted as CSV. If you mean some arbitrary text file with some other format then, no, it won't work.